# Get the domain name of a WCF request?

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5

How can I obtain the domain name or full URL of the requester?

Comment: Did you mean the URL used to access the service?  The identity of the client?

Comment: No the refering domain of the client.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that I understand your question, but if you need the domain name of the Windows user making the call to a service operation, use this:

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```

This will return "{domain}\{username}".

Try this and let me know what you think (you'll probably want to paste this code into an mstest project):

```
[TestClass]
public class AlternativeCredentials
{
    // Contracts
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IMyContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetUserName();
    }

    // Service
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    class MyService : IMyContract
    {
        public string GetUserName()
        {
            return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
        }
    }

    // Client
    class MyContractClient : ClientBase<IMyContract>, IMyContract
    {
        public MyContractClient() { }
        public MyContractClient(Binding binding, string address) :
            base(binding, new EndpointAddress(address)) { }

        public string GetUserName()
        { return Channel.GetUserName(); }
    }

    #region Host
    static string address = "net.tcp://localhost:8001/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    static ServiceHost host;

    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyContract), new NetTcpBinding(), address);
        host.Open();
    }

    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void MyClassCleanup()
    {
        if (host.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            host.Close();
    }
    #endregion  

    [TestMethod]
    public void UseUserNameCredentials()
    {
        using (MyContractClient proxy =
            new MyContractClient(new NetTcpBinding(), address))
        {
            proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUsername";
            proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword";

            proxy.Open();
            Assert.AreEqual("EMS\\magood", proxy.GetUserName());
            proxy.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After thinking about this for a minute, I am not usuing any security on the actual service. If I call this method, would it show me what user is currenlty running the process? I think it would show me the domain/username of the system account running the service. Right?

Comment: In the example I added above, "EMS\magood" is my Windows identity.  WCF defaults to ClientCredentialType = Windows.  You can change this to Basic for TCP bindings.  What kind of Binding are you using?

Comment: Some of our clients need to use the BasicHTTP binding without any security. Without having to to rely on IIS to filter IP addresses, I was hoping to check the domain name of the incoming request. When I created a similar example I got back the user account that is running the service. In this case it was our interal account we use for IIS authentication OurUser\OurDomainName. I was looking for something like www.TheRequestersDomain.com