# Get Requesting Domain Name from WCF request?

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5

I asked this question: [Get the domain name of a WCF request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935854/get-the-domain-name-of-a-wcf-request)

Is it not possible to get the requesting domain from a WCF request? So for anonymous request that do not require authentication, how can I get the domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a number of misconception on how TCP/IP works. First, not every computer or process in the world *has* a URL. So asking "what is the URL of the requester" (as you did in the previous question) is a meaningless question.

It is slightly more meaningful to ask for the DNS name of the machine that originates a request. Not every machine in the internet has a DNS name, but many do. To find out what the DNS name of a machine is, you first need its IP address, which you have if you received a request from the machine over TCP or UDP (since that will include the requester's IP address). You can then perform a reverse DNS lookup to determine the DNS name; whether this gives you anything, or whether the result is correct depends on how the reverse DNS is managed for the requester.

According to [this blog entry](http://maonet.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/customerize-wcf-authorization/), you can use the IncomingMessageProperties, looking at RemoteEndpointMessageProperty, to find out what the remote IP is.

Comment: Actually, you still might not have the actual IP address of the requester. You could be getting the address of a proxy server or NAT device.

Comment: Good point. I didn't think about that! I guess I was under the impression that the our requests would be coming from a specific domain. I wanted to omplement something like the Google Maps API key. They somehow embed the domain name int he key.