# WCF authentication methods when calling from Jquery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-security

Does anyone have some good suggestions when it comes to authenticating clients using JQuery or JavaScript? I realize that any JavaScript client is going to send clear text, but has anyone come up with a good solution to mask the authentication?

One thought I had, was to limit the requests per domain. I had written this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935854/get-the-domain-name-of-a-wcf-request) a while back asking if there was a way to get the calling domain to a wcf service. So, I could issue an encrypted token to the user. So, when they make a call they pass that token in and in that token is their calling domain. If the actual calling domain and the token's version do not match up, then they are not authenticated.

Comment: javascript is sourcecode, which means passwords would be exposed. which means you might aswell print the on the screen in my opinion. whats wrong with the server side auth?or ajax?

Comment: I know and I sort of stated the clear text issue above. I am using AJAX to call the service, but my question was how to deal with authentication and possibly an example with JAvascript or JQuery. The servcies are in .net 4.0, but the client is only using javascript or JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like [this](http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/523/oauth-dot-net) idea