# How to get client domain name from a request

Tags: c#, wcf

I have wcf-service host at `kkk.com`. When someone(other domain) request to my service I use this code to get client's domain name.

```
public static string GetClientDomian(HttpContext context)
{
    string clientDomain = string.Empty;
    clientDomain = context.Request.Url.Host;

    return clientDomain;
}
```

But it's always return `kkk.com` not return the client's domain name. How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935854/get-the-domain-name-of-a-wcf-request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. This code is work. Change `context.Request.Url.Host` to `context.Request.UrlReferrer.Host`

Like this

```
public static string GetClientDomian(HttpContext context)
{
    string clientDomain = string.Empty;
    clientDomain = context.Request.UrlReferrer.Host;

    return clientDomain;
}
```